# Objective-C - Rotation inside modal even shouldAutoRotate = false

Tags: ios

I have a view (InfoVC) that is rotating even if I set shouldAutoRotate to false.
This is the code that is opening the view (inside a Modal)

```
- (IBAction)presentInfoVC:(id)sender{
    InfoVC *infoVC = [[InfoVC alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *infoNVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:infoVC];

    UIImage *img =[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];



    infoNVC.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [infoNVC.navigationBar.topItem setTitleView:imgView];
    [imgView release];

    [self presentModalViewController:infoNVC animated:YES];

    [infoVC release];

}
```

and the code that was supposed to avoid this view to rotate (inside InfoVC.m):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return FALSE;    
}
```

What is wrong?

Regards!

Comment: is your shouldautorotate method getting called??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a subclass of `UINavigationController`, you could use a category to perform the same task (if it's required for all instances of UINavigationController). It's a lot more lightweight than the subclassing method, and doesn't require you to swap class types for pre-existing `UINavigationController`s.

To do so is as follows:

**UINavigationController+NoRotate.h**

```
@interface UINavigationController(NoRotate) 
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate;
@end
```

**UINavigationController_NoRotate.m**

```
#import "UINavigationController+NoRotate.h"

@implementation UINavigationController (NoRotate)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

@end
```

From then on, if you need a `UINavigationController` to no longer rotate, simply import `UINavigationController+NoRotate.h` where required. As category overrides will affect all instances of the class, if you need this behaviour for only a few cases, then you will need to subclass UINavigationController, and override `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I figured out that I was supposed to implement shoulAutorotate in the UINavigationController, not in UIViewController. I created another class (subclass of UINavigationController), implemented shouldAutorotate like in this view and I used it replacing UINavigationController.

Code:

UINavigationControllerNotRotate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UINavigationControllerNotRotate : UINavigationController

@end
```

UINavigationControllerNotRotate.m

```
#import "UINavigationControllerNotRotate.h"

@interface UINavigationControllerNotRotate ()

@end

@implementation UINavigationControllerNotRotate

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return FALSE;
}

@end
```

New code:

```
- (IBAction)presentInfoVC:(id)sender{

    InfoVC *infoVC = [[InfoVC alloc] init];
    UINavigationControllerNotRotate *infoNVC = [[UINavigationControllerNotRotate alloc] initWithRootViewController:infoVC];

    UIImage *img =[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_vejasp_topbar.png"];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];


    infoNVC.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [infoNVC.navigationBar.topItem setTitleView:imgView];
    [imgView release];

    [self presentModalViewController:infoNVC animated:YES];

    [infoVC release];

}
```

This worked fine for me. Thanks for everybody who tried to help!